# Loading specific model file from CoreNLP Model jar file rather than a local copy of it

Tags: java, maven, stanford-nlp

Can refer to the already packaged model in StanfordCoreNLP library jar, instead of having duplicate copy of the model in the project working directory for this purpose?.

```
Properties configuration = new Properties();
configuration.put("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner");
configuration.put("ner.model", "english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
StanfordCoreNLP coreNLP  = new StanfordCoreNLP(configuration);
```

ps: The question was a part of another **SO** question which went unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This path:

`edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz`

is in stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar.

So if you put that in your properties, it will be loaded from the jar.

Answer (score 0):

To add any model that is existing in a jar file, expand the jar files as shown in the picture below and copy the qualified name of the model you want.
Note: remove the first "/" in the copied name before adding it to the properties of the pipeline.
[Adding name of a model from jar files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJQnh.png)